# C# 'live' parsing of input from TextBox

Tags: c#, parsing, windows-forms-designer

I have following problem. I use Windows Forms for simple calculations, and want that the app will calculate the values live based on the input provided into text box. So even if my desired input in the `TextBox` is 3-digit number, it will calculate the results even for the first digit. Even triggering the calculations is `TextBoxChanged`.

The problem is when I try to provide negative number.

so here is the code, I provide some value into `TextBox` called `dim1`:

```
private void dim1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkInput(dim1))
            {
                RunClac();
            }
        }
```

Checking input:

```
public const NumberStyles numstyle = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite;

        public bool checkInput(TextBox tb)
        {
            // bool check = Double.TryParse(tb.Text, out val);
            bool check = double.TryParse(tb.Text,numstyle,null, out double val);
                if (!(tb.Text == "") && check)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else //(tb.Text == "")
                {
                    tb.Text = "1";
                    tb.SelectAll();
                    return false;
                }
        }
```

Once input is checked `RunCalc` goes as this:

```
public void RunClac()
{
double bplate = double.Parse(dim1.Text);
...
}
```

The problem is that `TryParse` do not allow to have negative number as the first character from the string. Even if I change the `InputCheck` as shown below (`or` instead of `and` in first `if`) the program crasahes on parsing anyway.

```
public const NumberStyles numstyle = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite;

        public bool checkInput(TextBox tb)
        {
            // bool check = Double.TryParse(tb.Text, out val);
            bool check = double.TryParse(tb.Text,numstyle,null, out double val);
                if (!(tb.Text == "") **|** check)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else //(tb.Text == "")
                {
                    tb.Text = "1";
                    tb.SelectAll();
                    return false;
                }
        }
```

What is the best solution for it?

Comment: Do you have an particular input that cause the issue ? I don't think I can reproduce your issue : https://dotnetfiddle.net/4E48BX . I nontice in your code you are using `|` instead of `||`, any particular reason ? perhaps you don't want to trigger for first char "-", and want to be on validated not changed?

Comment: Don't change the textbox Text in the checkInput method. Only do what the method name tells you. Check the value. When parsing contents of something there will always be cases that from going to a valid input there will be invalid values on the way. If you reset the textbox then its unhelpful (to not say its mean).

Comment: When you only want to allow 0-9 maybe prevent inserting everything else in the first place? There should be a gazillion implementation of NumberTextbox(es) out there.

Comment: the problem starts when I start typing the number from minus sign "-" or dot (to put decimal number without zero in front) like ".5" inestead of "0.5".

Comment: What is `**|** check`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is this code:

```
tb.Text = "1";
tb.SelectAll();
```

If I understand the code correctly this should immediately replace `-` with a `1`, thus preventing negative numbers from being entered.

You could perhaps add a special check for this, something like

```
else if(tb.Text.Trim() = '-'){
  return false;
}
```

But my recommendation would be some other way to inform the user that the number is invalid, for example:

```
if(double.TryParse(tb.Text, out var value)){
   tbBorder.Color = Colors.Transparent;
   RunClac(value);
}
else{
   tbBorder.Color = Colors.Red;
}
```

This way the users text is never replaced. So if the user pastes "123abc" he can just edit the text. See also [ErrorProviders](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-error-provider-control-in-windows-forms-and-C-Sharp/) for a more systematic way to inform the users of input errors.

Answer (score 0):

JonasH guided me to the solution. So I had to distinguish two scenarios, where I allow the negative values and not.

this leads to methods as follows:

- for input that must not be negative:

```
public bool checkInputDimensions(TextBox tb)
        {
            // bool check = Double.TryParse(tb.Text, out val);
            bool check = double.TryParse(tb.Text, numstyle, null, out double val);
            bool result;
            if (!(tb.Text == "") && check)
            {
                tb.BackColor = default(Color);
                result= true;
            }
            else if (tb.Text == "")
            {
                tb.Text = "0";
                tb.SelectAll();
                result = true;
                tb.BackColor = default(Color);
            }
            else if (tb.Text == "-")
            {
                tb.Text = "0";
                tb.SelectAll();
                result = true;
                tb.BackColor = default(Color);
            }
            else if (tb.Text == ".")
            {
                tb.Text = "0.";
                result = false;
                tb.BackColor = default(Color);
                tb.Focus();
                tb.SelectionStart = tb.Text.Length;
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
                tb.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

and for the input that can be negative numbers:

```
   public bool checkInputCorr(TextBox tb)
        {
            // bool check = Double.TryParse(tb.Text, out val);
            bool check = double.TryParse(tb.Text,numstyle,null, out double val);
            bool result;   
            if (!(tb.Text == "") && check)
            {
                tb.BackColor = default(Color);
                result = true;
            }
            else if (tb.Text == "")
            {
                tb.Text = "0";
                result = true;
                tb.BackColor = default(Color);
                tb.Focus();
                tb.SelectionStart = tb.Text.Length;
            }
            else if (tb.Text == "-") 
            {
                tb.Text = "-";
                result = false;
                tb.BackColor = Color.Red;
                tb.Focus();
                tb.SelectionStart = tb.Text.Length;
            }
            else if (tb.Text == ".")
            {
                tb.Text = "0.";
                result = false;
                tb.BackColor = default(Color);
                tb.Focus();
                tb.SelectionStart = tb.Text.Length;
            }
            else
            {
                result= false;
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
                tb.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

probably there are more elegant ways to do it, but for now works enough for me.